# Grouping posted values for echo after they're submitted

Tags: php

Whats the best way to print the meterage1 and product1 posts as a single related string value when i loop through the foreach? So for example, product1 input box value which is related to meterage1 and product2 relates to meterage2.

Here is my form:

```
  <form id="orderform" name"orderForm" action="tomypage.php" method="post">
    <a  id="add">+</a>
     <table id="ordertable" width="533" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="33%">Product Code (e.g 66203)</td>
          <td width="33%">mtrs sq Required (e.g 10)</td>
          <td width="33%">Preview Image</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
          <td class="prodcode"><input type="text" name="prodcode" id="prodcode" /></td>
          <td class="meterage"><input type="text" name="meterage" id="meterage" /></td>
          <td class="imgsample"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
          <td class="prodcode"><input type="text" name="prodcode1" id="prodcode" /></td>
          <td class="meterage"><input type="text" name="meterage1" id="meterage" /></td>
          <td class="imgsample"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item">
          <td class="prodcode"><input type="text" name="prodcode2" id="prodcode" /></td>
          <td class="meterage"><input type="text" name="meterage2" id="meterage" /></td>
          <td class="imgsample"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

My current PHP foreach:

```
if ($_POST) { 
      foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { 
            $orderdetails = $key.'&nbsp;'.$value.'m<sup>2</sup><br />'; 
      } 
} else { 
      $orderdetails = 'No Order Details Selected'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign form fields to an array, instead of numbering them, this will give you far more flexibility when accessing their values: i.e.

```
<input type="text" name="meterage[]" />
<input type="text" name="meterage[]"  />
<input type="text" name="meterage[]"  />
```

Then simply do:

```
print_r($_POST['meterage']);
```

Or access the `$_POST['meterage']` array as required (i.e. loop through for action on each value).

If you then want to loop through the fieldsets, for related products/meterages, you could us:

```
$number_of_products=count($_POST['prodcode']);
for ( $i=0; $i<$number_of_products; $i++){
     echo $_POST['prodcode'][$i]." has the meterage: ".$_POST['meterage'][$i]."<br/>";
}
```

Comment: But would that would group it with the associated product?

Comment: It depends on the structure of your form, but because they are listed here sequentially, yes. meterage[1] would be the meterage field beneath prodcode[1]

Comment: You can also produce a multidimensional array from form fields, again depending on whether its appropriate in the context. So you could have meterage['productname'][] if there were more than one meterage field per product...

Comment: If you want to simply add the result into a textfield, set the textfield's value to the php: implode(" ", $_POST['meterage'])

Comment: ..or... using a for each loop, you can define $i=0 to number of products, then on each iteration of the loop, meterage[$i] will related to product[$i]

Comment: OK, its tricky because the rows are being dynamically generated by jquery, and a new name is being created for each...i understand the concept though

Comment: If the rows are being dynamically generated, I'd probably alter the Javascript- not least of all to correct the fact the IDs for the fields are being replicated which is not standard compliant practice :S

Comment: Thanks for the advice Ergo, i'll look at altering it.